# Teredo and IPV6 web servers

Tags: vps, ipv6, ipv4, teredo

I have two different questions, the first one could be stupid.
I was reading about IPV6 and ended up in this site http://test-ipv6.com/  that says that I have a public IPV6 with Teredo tunneling. I don't understand if this Teredo is a software thing, does it have to with my ISP, is it enabled by Windows, how do I get that IPV6 IP, where does it come from? I have windows 7.

Second question, I have a VPS with IPV6 connectivity only I can connect to it (apparently thanks to Teredo) and visit pages from the web server using IPV6 IP directly into the browser, is it possibile to host a website on there accessible by the IPV4 network? maybe some dns servers than tunnel traffic from IPV4(user) to IPV6(server)?

Thank you

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teredo_tunneling

Answer (score 1):

Teredo is basically a way to encapsulate IPv6 packets in IPv4 UDP packets. It allows you to have IPv6 connectivity even if your ISP does not assign you an IPv6 address. There are a number of publicly accessible Teredo relays to route your encapsulated traffic to IPv6 network. Your Win7 host has a virtual Teredo network adapter with an IPv6 address assigned to it.

Comment: so It's a software solution connected to remote servers that give you the IP? Every host could have if they have Teredo installed? It has nothing to do with the ISP right? Who pays for the Teredo relays?